# Creating responsive rating buttons in javascript/html

Tags: javascript, php, html, button

We have an assignment in school to improve project, without actually knowing the programming languages. We got the skeleton of the project and we must add some functionality to it.

The skeleton is a blog, that has a login/register/ and you can create, edit and delete articles.

My first idea is to add two buttons - like and dislike, linked to a variable. Clicking the like button will increase the rating with 1, and dislike will decrease it. I added the buttons but I'm struggling with the javascript code. It should look something like this:

```
 <script>
     var rating = 0;

     function IncreaseRating() {
         document.getElementById('like').value = ++rating;
     };
     function DecreaseRating() {
         document.getElementById('dislike').value = --rating;
     };
 </script>
 <button id="like" type="button" onclick="IncreaseRating()">Like</button>
 <button id="dislike" type="button" onclick="DecreaseRating()">Dislike</button>
 <script>document.write(rating)</script>
```

but it is not working. Somehow I managed to display the rating value, but it does not increase nor decrease. How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Your issue is that you only output `rating` on page load. Both your functions only change the value of `rating`, but neither update the already displayed value.

Answer (score 0):

The order of your code is the problem, you run your script tag BEFORE the elements are included in the DOM.

To fix it, just change the order, put the script tag at the very bottom of the document, right before the closing  tag.

```
<button id="like" type="button" onclick="IncreaseRating()">Like</button>
<button id="dislike" type="button" onclick="DecreaseRating()">Dislike</button>
<script>
    var rating = 0;

    function IncreaseRating() {
        document.getElementById('like').value = ++rating;
    };
    function DecreaseRating() {
        document.getElementById('dislike').value = --rating;
    };
</script>

<script>document.write(rating)</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried this code? As the `document.write()` is not inside either function, then when the `rating` is changed, nothing will happen as it was already output on page load.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're calling your scripts in the body after you create your elements. The issue with that is, you've told your element to call function ***X*** but it cant find it as its not yet been declared (you declare it right after you create the element).

There are two solutions:

- Use jQuery's event handling to handle the DOM element events like so:`$('#like').click(function() { //actions here });`
- Or put your native Javascript code in your header with your meta data thus it is loaded and your functions are declared on page load (before your elements are created).

https://jsfiddle.net/h6sveuju/7/

Notice how if you click the Javascript settings you see that the

> Load Type

is set to

> No wrap - in

Also you're trying to increment the text of the buttons which are currently strings (*Like* and *Dislike*) which obviously is wrong as it would update the text of the buttons to be just the value of the rating thus leaving the button text something like *12*.

Comment: The code is working, but there is a problem.When i refresh the page, rating goes back to zero. How can i save it?

Comment: Well the question is, where do you want to save the value? If its a database, then you want to create an SQL connection on your server and load the value into to the page. When you click one of the buttons you create a request to save the new value to the database thus when the page is reloaded the value is loaded.

Comment: I want to map the value to the article. Each article has a title, content, id, category and tags, why cant i add a default rating variable of 0 and increase it with the script? And if this is possible, how can i do it. I have zero to none knowledge in javascript/php and that makes the task almost impossible...

Comment: In PHP you want to access the database (assuming you're using one), grab the current rating of the article you're loading and then when you write to the page in PHP you want to modify the <script> element where your button events are located and place that value in the 'var rating = <?php echo $value_from_DB; ?>' thus once the page loads the counter will start on the number that was allocated previously.